# RecyclerView not displaying data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-support-library

I have a RecyclerView, which is a BottomSheet, from 23.2 support library:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_multi_car"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_sheet_height"
        android:background="@color/background"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"/>
```

Initially, I create adapter with empty dataset:

```
    mMultiCarAdapter = new CarListRecyclerAdapter();
    bottomSheetMultiCar.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL_LIST));
    bottomSheetMultiCar.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    bottomSheetMultiCar.setAdapter(mMultiCarAdapter);
    ...

public static class CarListRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CarListRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Car> mCars = new ArrayList<>();
```

I have a method to replace my data:

```
    public void replaceItems(final List<Car> cars) {
        mCars.clear();
        mCars.addAll(cars);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

I show the RecyclerView:

```
private void showMultiCar(final List<Car> cars) {
    mBottomSheetMultiCarBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);

    mMultiCarAdapter.replaceItems(cars);
}
```

After I show the RecyclerView, it appears(I see a BottomSheet with RecyclerView's background color). However, no items are visible... until I do some action. Confirmed actions that make RecyclerView show items:

- I change visibility of other views;
- I click RecyclerView

I tried multiple things.

First, changing visibility of RecyclerView after adding items, but it appears that some time must pass for that to be effective.

I tried several methods on it: requestLayout, invalidate.

Comment: Yes. As I mentioned, items appear after some ui event.

Answer (score 2):

The recyclerView needs to be a fixed size:

```
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

Took way too long to figure this out. Not sure *why* it works, but it does.